# Select function to run based on command line args in Rust

Tags: rust

I am solving Project Euler with Rust. I want to create a file that has a solution for a specific problem. And the `main` function executes the function to solve a problem specified by a command line argument. For example, the following command will solve problem 11.

```
$ euler-rs 11
```

To do this, I structured the project like the following.

```
euler-rs // project root
  + src
    + main.rs
    + p001.rs // module for problem 1
    + p002.rs // module for problem 2
    ...
    + util.rs // module for utils
```

Each module has function `sol() -> u64`.

And wrote `main` function like this:

```
mod p001;
mod p002;
...

fn main() {
  ...
  let prob_no = match args[1].parse::<u32> {
    Ok(n) => n,
    Err(_) => { ... // error handling }
  }

  let sol match prob_no {
    1 => p001::sol,
    2 => p002::sol,
    ...
    _ => { ... // error handling }
  }
}
```

This works fine. The problem is that I have to add `mod p***` and `* => p***::sol,` whenever I add a new solution.

I am not sure if this is the best way to handle my requirement. How can I avoid adding the two (`mod p***` and `* => p***::sol,`) when I add a new solution?

Regarding module structure, I tried to move all `p***.rs` to a subdirectory like `/sol/p001.rs`, but ended up with moving the `mod p001` to `mod.rs` file in that subdirectory.

Comment: At some point you'll have to enumerate them. Rust provides no means of runtime reflection on modules.

Comment: I solved a similar problem by using a `build.rs` based solution, for the Advent Of Code challenge, see: https://github.com/noirotm/advent-of-code-2021/blob/master/build.rs
That might not be the most elegant solution, but has served me well over the years :)

Comment: `build.rs` is not a good solution here. What you want is a proc macro.